# I am trying to connect my web page to my local server database but I am getting error ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
 errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000,
  fatal: true
```

I am using Mac OS and VS Code to connect to my local server. I have connected mysql workbench to VSCode as well and it is working fine. But when I try to connect it with my program it is not working. I changed the hostname from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' as well still no luck. Also, I changed my port from 3306 to 3000 as it was not connecting and I got the following error

```
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'usersql'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
```

My code:

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql')

const pool = createPool({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "usersql",
    password: "password!23",
    database: "userdb",
    connectionLimit: 10,
    port: 3000
})

pool.query(`select * from userdb.New_Customer`, function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    return console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: It's a login failure. The reason can be anything from active firewall, to wrong authetication mode to wrong user credentials.

Comment: this might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working. The reason was I used `!` in my password. After I altered it started working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a login failure. The reason can be anything from active firewall, to wrong authentication mode to wrong user credentials.
this might help you, [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)